# Summation of series

Tags: summation

Find $\sum_1^n$ $\frac {2r+1}{r^2(r+1)^2}$ 
Also, find the sum to infinity of the series.
I tried decomposing it into partial fractions of the form $\frac Ar$ + $\frac{B}{r^2}$ + $\frac{C}{(r+1)}$ + $\frac{D}{(r+1)^2}$ but it was getting too complicated and tedious. Is there some trick here that i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track! Clearing the fractions, we have:
$$
2r + 1 = Ar(r + 1)^2 + B(r + 1)^2 + Cr^2(r + 1) + Dr^2
$$
Comparing coefficients, we have:
\begin{align*}
\boxed{r^3}:\qquad 0 &= A + C \\
\boxed{r^2}:\qquad 0 &= 2A + B + C + D \\
\boxed{r^1}:\qquad 2 &= A + 2B \\
\boxed{r^0}:\qquad 1 &= B \\
\end{align*}
Substituting, notice that $B = 1 \implies A = 0 \implies C = 0 \implies D = -1$. Hence, we obtain a telescoping series:
$$
\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac {2r+1}{r^2(r+1)^2} = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{r^2} - \frac{1}{(r + 1)^2} \right]
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac{1}{1^2} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2} \right] = 1
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac1{r^2} - \frac1{(r+1)^2} = \frac{(r+1)^2-r^2}{r^2(r+1)^2} = \frac{(r^2+2r+1)-r^2}{r^2(r+1)^2} = \frac{2r+1}{r^2(r+1)^2}
$$

The thing that suggested this to me is that $\displaystyle 2r+1 = 2\left(r+\frac12\right)$, and $r+\dfrac12$ is half-way between $r+0$ and $r+1$, the two expressions in the denominator.

Next, you rely on the fact that the sum telescopes, so nearly all of the terms vanish.